# Pandas where condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset as shown below

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'A': [0,0, 0, 0,0,0,1],
                   'B': [0,0, 1, 0,0,0,0],
                   'C': [0,1, 0, 0,0,0,1],
                   'D': [0,0, 1, 0,0,0,1],
                   'E': [0,0, 0, 0,0,0,1],
                   })
```

[image]

Trying to creating a column flag at the end with a condition where if 'number'<=5 and (A!=0|B!=0|c!=0|D!=0|E!=0) then 1 else 0.

```
np.where(((test['number']<=5) & 
((test['A']!=0) | 
 (test['B']!=0) |
   (test['C']!=0) |
    (test['D']!=0) |
     (test['E']!=0))),1,0)
```

This worked out but I am trying to simplify the query by not hard encoding the columns names A/B/C/D/E as they change(names may change and also number of columns may also change). Only one column remains static which is 'number' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas-dataframe-any) on axis=1 instead of joining with `|`:

```
test['flag'] = np.where(
    test['number'].le(5) &
    test.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).any(axis=1), 1, 0
)
```

`test`:

```
   number  A  B  C  D  E  flag
0       1  0  0  0  0  0     0
1       2  0  0  1  0  0     1
2       3  0  1  0  1  0     1
3       4  0  0  0  0  0     0
4       5  0  0  0  0  0     0
5       6  0  0  0  0  0     0
6       7  1  0  1  1  1     0
```

Lot's of options to select columns:

1. Select by location `iloc` all columns the first and after -> `test.iloc[:, 1:]`
2. Select by `loc` all columns 'A' and after -> `test.loc[:, 'A':]`
3. Select all columns except 'number' with [Index.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) -> `test[test.columns.difference(['number'])]`

Comment: Can also use a `sum(abs(...))` and if the sum is > 0 set flag to 1